# Odoo 10 search active and inactive records using search() method

Tags: python-2.7, orm, odoo, odoo-10

I have many2many field location_from_ids and trying to find all the childs of location_ids.

```
  location_from_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='stock.location',relation='report_stock_config_location_from_rel',column1='report_id',column2='location_id',string='Locations From', context={'active_test': False})
```

I am using search() method to get all the childs of location_ids:

```
def _get_filter(self, report):
    res = ''
    if report.location_from_ids:
        location_ids = [l.id for l in report.location_from_ids]
        locations = self.env['stock.location'].search([('id', 'child_of', location_ids), ('active', 'in', ('t', 'f'))])
```

I need to get all the locations (active and inactive) but getting only active records. How can I achieve to get all the records: active and inactive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just "deactivate" the active test on searches:

```py
locations = self.env['stock.location'].with_context(
    active_test=False).search(
        [('id', 'child_of', location_ids)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Como complemento a la respuesta, es bueno revisar las operaciones que soporta los records en odoo
https://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/environment.html#environment

Supported Operations
RecordSet also support set operations you can add, union and intersect, ... recordset:

record in recset1       # include
record not in recset1   # not include
recset1 + recset2       # extend
recset1 | recset2       # union
recset1 & recset2       # intersect
recset1 - recset2       # difference
recset.copy()           # to copy recordset (not a deep copy)

Comment: Hi, is it possible for you to post your answer in english?