# Odoo: search_count do not show archived record

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I have a button called job_count which links jobs to equipment. It is only showing active records of job, But, I want to show the count of all the active as well as an archived record of jobs associated with equipment. Please help.

```
  def _get_job_count(self):
      for record in self:
          j_count = self.env['job_module'].sudo().search_count([('equipment_id', 'in', self.ids)]])
          record.job_count= j_count
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Odoo 10 search active and inactive records using search() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708159/odoo-10-search-active-and-inactive-records-using-search-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**active**
*toggles the global visibility of the record, if active is set to `False` the record is invisible in most searches and listing.*

You can manually tell the search method to find also archived records by adding the following criteria to the search domain:

```
 '|', ('active','=',True),  ('active','=',False)
```

*Example*:

```
search_count([('equipment_id', 'in', self.ids), '|', ('active','=',True),  ('active','=',False)])
```

### Shortcut:

Odoo provide a shortcut to set the `active` flag, you just need to specify `active_test` in the context.

> whether the default filtering of records with `active`
> field set to `False` should be applied.

In old API, the `active_test` is passed through the `context` parameter:

```
.search_count(cr, uid, domain, context=dict(context, active_test=False))
```

In new API, you can use `with_context` method to update the search context:

```
self.with_context(active_test=False).search_count(domain)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add context **active_test=False**.

```
 def _get_job_count(self):
      for record in self:
          j_count = self.env['job_module'].sudo().with_context(active_test=False).search_count([('equipment_id', 'in', self.ids)]])
          record.job_count= j_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by getting a count of both active and archive records individually and then by adding them together.

```
  def _get_job_count(self):
      for record in self:
          j_count1 = self.env['job_module'].sudo().search_count([('active','=',False), 
            ('equipment_id', 'in', self.ids)]])
          j_count2 = self.env['job_module'].sudo().search_count([('active','=',True), 
            ('equipment_id', 'in', self.ids)]])
          record.job_count= j_count1 + j_count2
```